# Navigation Bar not showing in Storyboard, but showing in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a navigation controller, a viewcontroller 1, and a viewcontroller 2. In my vc1, the navbar shows as it should, with an editable title, I can add uibarbutton items to it. My problem is by the vc 2. I do see a navigation bar, but I can't add buttons or set a title in the storyboard. In the outline layout, I see a navbar by the vc 1, but by vc 2 i see top layout guide.

The weird thing is that when I set a title to vc 2 programmaticaly, I actually see the set title in the simulator.

Is there a way I can edit the navbar on vc 2 in the storyboard?

I'm kinda new at this, so please don't be too harsh on me.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Delete it and re-add it and see what happens.

Comment: Can you add some screen shots to help illuminate your problem?

Comment: is vc1 one the `rootViewController` of your `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @MikeSteevson anything still unclear? otherwise could you tick the green checkmark? :)

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is indeed completely **natural**.

This is because `UINavigationController` uses a dynamic mechanism to manage its *stack* of view controllers that is not in the scope of Storyboards edits. You will have to customize your `UINavigationBar` programmatically, in Storyboards this unfortunately not possible, at least not if you're using `UINavigationController`. You can however drag & drop a `UINavigationBar` onto your `UIViewcontroller` directly in Storyboards and customize that one as you like, only the one that is managed by the `UINavigationController` will not be editable in that way.